Give an example of an origin-passing function that is continuous not Lipschitz and its integral on a interval $[0,b]$, $b>0$ is infinite
Does there exist a function $f(x)$ such that

it is continuous but not Lipschitz on $[0,b],b>0$ (not Lipschitz near $0$) and $f(0)=0, f(x) >0, \forall x \in (0,b]$.
the integral $\int_{0}^{b}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx = \infty$.

For example, the function $f(x) =x$ is Lipschitz on $[0,1],f(0) =0$ and the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx = -\ln 0 = \infty$.
The Lipschitz can guarantee that $\int_{0}^{b}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx = \infty$ since:
$\forall x \in (0,b], |f(x) - f(0)| \leq L|x-0| \Rightarrow \forall x \in (0,b],\frac{1}{f(x)} \geq \frac{1}{Lx} \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx \geq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{Lx}dx=-\frac{1}{L}\ln 0 =\infty$.
Is there a function that is just continuous on $[0,b],b>0$ and $f(0)=0, f(x) >0, \forall x \in (0,b]$ such that $\int_{0}^{b}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx = \infty$?

For example $x^2(\sqrt{1-x}+1)$ in $[0,1]$

A Lipschitz function is always continuous. What you asked is not the correct question.

@LidingYao: But a continuous function is not necessarily Lipschitz, so the question makes sense.

@Gonçalo Sorry I misunderstood.

Take $f(x)=-x\log x$, it is not Lipschitz at 0 but has infinite integral.
